# Hydra ( Host Offline redoing attempt)

Tags: hydra

I tried to  brute force a http-get service  using -M option with list of servers of which some host are down/offline.

However when hydra reaches to offline host it tries to redo-attempt many times on the same offline server which makes hydra very slow.

Syntax provided

```
 hydra -l admin -p admin -M (Target ip list) -f -V -t 5 -w 5  http-get
```

How can i skip offline host from Target ip list so that no redo attempt on offline host

Because of some offline server in -M (Target list) hydra is not proceeding/taking more time due to re attempt on offline server

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Hydra tries to connect at each IP, shorten your IP List with IPs existent.

If you look into the details:

Before you can create an http connection (Application Layer of the [OSI Model](https://sockets%20happen%20at%20the%20session%20layer%20of%20the%20OSI%20Model.)) you need a socket (Session Layer).

First, hydra tries to create a socket to each ip in the list (verified with version 9.4: https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/tree/v9.4). If the socket can not be established it kills the current process holding the socket.
If a socket can be found it tries to connect using http/s.
Thus, if there is no server it still tries to connect in the first place.

Example with an IP List where one IP exist and the other not:

[image: Example]

If you look into the code:

[image: failed connection attempt]
https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/v9.4/hydra-http.c#L389

There are 3 connection attempts.
You could disable the redo attempts with [`-K`](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/435) but then you still have one attempt left.

[image: no reconnects]

You can circumvent this if you deliver hydra a tested ip file, e.g. using (if `ips.txt` is your target ip list):

```
rm ips_new.txt && for ip in $(cat ips.txt); do; [ ! -z "$(curl -Is http://$ip | head -1)" ] && echo $ip >> ips_new.txt ; done
```

After that invoke it with:

```
hydra -l admin -p admin -M ips_new.txt -f -V -t 5 -w 5  http-get
```